# CoveragePy command for measuring Code Coverage

Tags: python, windows, code-coverage, coverage.py

**Introduction**

A directory containing a `test` and `main` python file has been created. Executing a test works:

```
C:\...>py test/test.py
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

According to [this documentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html#cmd) it is possible to measure code coverage using the command line.

A number of commands has been issued:

```
C:\...>coverage run --source="C:\path\to\test"
Nothing to do.
Use 'coverage help' for help.
```

---

```
C:\...>coverage run --source "C:\path\to\test\main.py" -m "C:\path\to\test\test.py"
No module named 'C:\path\to\test\test.py'
```

without success.

**Question**

Which command needs to be issued in order to measure the code coverage of a Python file using CoveragePy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `coverage` to capture data, you run the tests *with* the coverage tool.  Something like this:

```
coverage run py test/test.py
```

Coverage can be awkward to get set up, but it's *incredibly* useful -- have fun!

> You collect execution data by running your Python program with the run
>   command:

```
$ coverage run my_program.py arg1 arg2
```

(from http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html#cmd)

Comment: Running `coverage run main.py test.py` and subsequently `coverage report` results in main 2 1 50%. Thank you. I will accept and upvote the answer.